# VC++ Argument value changes inside function when a function variable is initialize

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Below is the example code with which I am trying to explain the issue:

Environment: VC++ 2013 (Visual Studio) building an exe.

In the `main` function I have initialized a variable and assigned a value to it. 
After passing the variable to another function, inside that function I am initializing another array variable and setting its memset to 0. When I do that my parameter values also gets changed.

TCHAR == char (multibyte)

```
void CallFoo(DWORD val){
  TCHAR sStr[256];   // val == 111
  memset(sStr, 0, sizeof(sStr)); // val == 0  --- Strange Very strange. 
  ....
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){
 DWORD dwValue = 111; 
 CallFoo(dwValue);
 ....
}
```

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Forgot to mention  my TCHAR is char  Multi Byte charater TCHAR  == char

Comment: I don't know how/if it would cause your problem, but memset's third argument is the number of bytes. If TCHAR is multibyte, it won't be the same as the array size.

Comment: try `memset(sStr, 0, sizeof(sStr));`

Comment: How do you determine that `dwValue` changed? The debugger may be confused if `CallFoo` is the last statement in `main`.

Comment: Is `val` actually used anywhere in `CallFoo`?  Also, why do you believe `val` is changing -- are you viewing this in a debugger?

Comment: Why do you use `memset(sStr, 0, 256);` in the first place? What's wrong with `TCHAR sStr[256] = {0};`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org).  The behavior you describe should not happen with the code as shown.

Comment: Also `memset(sStr, 0, 256);` should be `memset(sStr, 0, sizeof(sStr));`

Comment: @G.M.  Yes I am looking the values in Debugger.